# Get element Id using class name in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

Here I have HTML tag dynamically generated by jQuery say..

```
<tr id="CustomerScreen" class="rows"></tr>
<tr id="TraderScreen" class="rows"></tr>
<tr id="DistributorScreen" class="rows"></tr>
```

I'll set all the dynamically created table row class name to row and after that I want to loop it using class name and get id of the specific row using each. But i couldn't get as such this is what I have tried..

```
$('.rows').each(function () {
            var ar = this.id;
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Can you create http://jsfiddle.net, for instance, to ilustrate your problem? Code looks to be correct

Comment: This is working here http://jsfiddle.net/a35s6/

Comment: put a console.log(ar) in it too see the output in your console.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code is correct (assuming a `});`), **provided** that the elements exist when you run it. In the loop, `ar` will receive `"CustomerScreen"`, then `"TraderScreen"`, then `"DistributorScreen"`.

Note the proviso above. So for instance, this will show those three `id` values in order:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr id="CustomerScreen" class="rows"></tr>
<tr id="TraderScreen" class="rows"></tr>
<tr id="DistributorScreen" class="rows"></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<script>
$('.rows').each(function () {
    var ar = this.id;
    console.log(ar);
});
</script>
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/iquriq/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/iquriq/1/edit)

...because the script is after the elements in the document.

In contrast, this will show nothing:

```
<script>
$('.rows').each(function () {
    var ar = this.id;
    console.log(ar);
});
</script>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr id="CustomerScreen" class="rows"></tr>
<tr id="TraderScreen" class="rows"></tr>
<tr id="DistributorScreen" class="rows"></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/iquriq/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/iquriq/2/edit)

...because the script is *above* the elements, and they don't exist yet when it runs.

That's one of the reasons it's usually best practice to put your scripts at the very end of the document, just prior to the closing `</body>` tag. Alternately, if you absolutely *have* to put the scripts above the elements, you can use the jQuery [`ready` event](http://api.jquery.com/ready):

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.rows').each(function () {
        var ar = this.id;
        console.log(ar);
    });
});
</script>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr id="CustomerScreen" class="rows"></tr>
<tr id="TraderScreen" class="rows"></tr>
<tr id="DistributorScreen" class="rows"></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/iquriq/3) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/iquriq/3/edit)

jQuery will run the function after the DOM is loaded. But this is really for use in library code; for your own page code, just put the script at the end.

Comment: Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/VCjLX/
Why can't I post it?